# How to calculate % returns with multiple sources?

Tags: percentages

I have $\$X$ in a certain investment with A% monthly return.

And I also have $\$Y$ in another investment with B% monthly return.

How do I calculate my overall % monthly return?

Should I give percentual weights to X and Y and multiply these weights per their respective % returns?

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall monthly return is simply a weighted average of monthly returns, that is, $$A\times \frac{X}{X+Y}+B\times \frac{Y}{X+Y}$$